# Boolean satisfiability problem in DrRacket

Tags: racket

Is there a way to solve a given SAT in DrRacket?
Do I have to define a list and work with if...or with cond?
E.g. if a not b, if c not d, if b then c.

```
define (sat-list a b c d )
(cond
(lst? (first lst)
(if (a) not b)...
```

Something like that or am I totally wrong?

Comment: Just to clarify - are you looking for a library that already implements this or are you looking for suggestions on how to implement it yourself?

Comment: I am looking for suggestions on how to implement it myself or if it is possible to implement it myself

Comment: Also just to clarify, are you looking for a DPLL solver or something more complex like CDCL, watched literals, etc.? @S.H.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for getting to this so late, but here is a super-bare bones sat solver. Note that this doesn't do even the basics like unit clause elimination and pure literal elimination (not to mention advances like CDCL, watched literals).

For the algorithm behind this, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DPLL_algorithm. The important bit is in `solve-prob`; everything else is helper functions.

```lisp
; [clause], {var}
(struct cnf (clauses var-set) #:transparent)
; [literal]
(struct clause (literals) #:transparent)
; var, bool
(struct literal (var sign) #:transparent)
; bool, either(hash(var, bool), false), either(number, false)
(struct solution (is-sat var-map solve-time))

; [clause] -> {var}
(define (clauses->var-set cs)
  (list->set
   (foldl
    (λ (c vs)
      (append (map literal-var (clause-literals c)) vs))
    empty
    cs)))

; literal -> literal
(define (negate-lit lit)
  (literal (literal-var lit) (not (literal-sign lit))))

; literal, clause -> clause
(define (remove-lit-in-clause lit cl)
  (clause (remove lit (clause-literals cl))))

; literal, clause -> boolean
(define (lit-in-clause? lit cl)
  (if (member lit (clause-literals cl)) #t #f))

; literal, cnf -> cnf
(define (remove-lit-in-cnf lit prob)
  (cnf
   (foldl
    (λ (c cs)
      (if (lit-in-clause? lit c)
          cs
          (cons (remove-lit-in-clause (negate-lit lit) c) cs)))
    empty
    (cnf-clauses prob))
   (set-remove (cnf-var-set prob) (literal-var lit))))

; cnf -> var, bool
(define (choose-var-in-prob prob)
  (values
   (set-first (cnf-var-set prob))
   #t))

; var, bool, cnf -> hash(var, bool), cnf
(define (assign-var-in-prob var sign prob)
  (values
   (hash var sign)
   (remove-lit-in-cnf (literal var sign) prob)))

; cnf -> bool
(define (has-empty-clause? prob)
  (ormap (compose empty? clause-literals) (cnf-clauses prob)))

; cnf -> bool
(define (has-no-clauses? prob)
  (empty? (cnf-clauses prob)))

; cnf -> either(hash(var, bool), false)
(define (solve-prob prob)
  (cond
    [(has-no-clauses? prob) (hash)]
    [(has-empty-clause? prob) #f]
    [else
     (let*-values ([(var sign) (choose-var-in-prob prob)]
                   [(l-assn l-simple-prob) (assign-var-in-prob var sign prob)])
       (define l-soln (solve-prob l-simple-prob))
       (if l-soln
           (hash-union l-assn l-soln)
           (let*-values ([(r-assn r-simple-prob) (assign-var-in-prob var (not sign) prob)])
             (define r-soln (solve-prob r-simple-prob))
             (if r-soln
                 (hash-union r-assn r-soln)
                 #f))))]))

; cnf -> solution
(define (solve prob)
  (define-values (lres ct rt gt)
    (time-apply solve-prob (list prob)))
  (define res (first lres))
  (if res
      (solution #t res ct)
      (solution #f #f ct)))
```